# Sitecore Installation on CM with Remote Database

Tags: installation

I am trying to install `Sitecore 9.2` on `CM (Azure Server VM)` with `SQL Database` present on another remote Azure server VM.

How should I provide database details i.e., the value of the `$SqlServer parameter` in installation script `(XP1-SingleDeveloper.ps1)` so that it is able to access the remote database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide full URL (or IP) to your SQL database. And make sure port 1433 is open. Also in the SQL Server Configuration Manager on your SQL Server VM: SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for MSSQLSERVER set TCP/IP to Enabled

I have not tried on Azure, but it worked for me on AWS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked by including ComputerName/DatabaseName in $SqlServer variable.